# Salt and Pepper noise of Contours function with GeoServer

Tags: contour, geoserver, smoothing, elevation

How to clean salt and pepper noise in Contours that are generated from a raster DEM using Geoserver.

Tried with [Geoserver_Raster_Styling](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/rendering-transform.html#rendering-transformations) and WPS_Extension of Geoserver

[image]

Any line smoothing algorithms or Raster smoothing algorithms that supports Geoserver, let me know.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "salt and pepper noise"? We also need to know more about your input data set and the settings you used for the contouring algorithm

Comment: also please don't use screen shots of the SLD code as it is hard to read and harder still to test